# i have 10000 images in a vector form how do i convert it for my Convolution neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to **Convolutional Neural Network**. Instead of getting my data in image format i have been given flattened images matrix which is *[10000x784]*.

*Means 10000 images of size 28x28*

Considering one image size is *28x28*, how should i give the data matrix to my input for CNN?

My model is:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
#model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(2500, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2500, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['mae','mse'])
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15)
#Fits model
history= model.fit(x_trained, y_train, epochs = 7000, validation_split = 0.2, shuffle= True, verbose = 1, callbacks=[callback])
```

I get error at *model.fit*.

P.S: I am doing regression and for every image i have one value as output

Comment: Use the `reshape()` function of numpy to reshape the images. `img = img.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1))`

Comment: There's also `reshape` node in [tf](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin with a `Reshape` layer:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Reshape((28, 28, 1), input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
# ...
```

Comment: I already tried that. But then at the model.fit() what should be X? Should i reshape here too?

Comment: @AR. If you add a reshape layer like this, then you keep your training data as `(num_images, 784)`. Alternatively, you could reshape your training and test data before feeding it to the Keras model, like `x_train.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)`, then you would not need to change the layers in the model.

Comment: Hi, i am training the same dataset with LSTM and get the following error.. what can i modify?
**Keras ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv_lst_m2d_16: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4**